# Field mapping features to different feature with different field names using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, append, field-mapping

I was trying to you this instead of field mapping because field mapping is hard to understand.

```
outfc = r'\\water.com\Blank.gdb\SewerCollection\ssLateralLine'
infc = r'\\water.com\Test.gdb\PW_Waste_Water\WastewaterUtilitySegment'

#The position of the fields must match, Name=Description etc.
outfcfield = ['INSTALLDATE', 'FACILITYID', 'SIZE', 'InstallationID', 'DOWNELEV', 'UPELEV', 'SIZE', 'LIFECYCLE', 'MATERIAL', 'PROJECTID_ADD', 'SEGMENTTYPE']
infcfields = ['equipDatePutInService', 'featureName', 'insideDiameter', 'installationId', 'invertElevationDownstream', 'invertElevationUom', 'nominalPipeSize', 'operationalStatus', 'pipeMaterial', 'projectId', 'wastewaterSegmentType']
icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(infc, infcfields)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(outfc, outfcfields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            try:
                icur.insertRow(row)
            except:
                pass
            print "row[0:]: "+str(row[0:])
del icur
```

The insert cursor script above work but it didn't add the features just there data. I need to copy my feature to a different GDB that has a different Schema.
I found the script below here https://community.esri.com/thread/185431-append-tool-and-field-mapping-help-examples and thought i could ad my data and see what happens then go from there.

```
import arcpy

append_layer = r'\\water.com\Test.gdb\PW_Waste_Water\WastewaterUtilitySegment'
target_layer = r'\\water.com\Blank.gdb\SewerCollection\ssLateralLine'


#This object looks like the empty grid of fields 
#you see when you first open the append tool in the toolbox
fieldmappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()

#Like when you manually choose a layer in the toolbox and it adds the fields to grid
fieldmappings.addTable(target_layer)
fieldmappings.addTable(append_layer)

#####Lets map fields that have different names!
list_of_fields_we_will_map = []
#Lets chuck some tuples into the list we made
list_of_fields_we_will_map.append(('equipDatePutInService', 'facilityNumber', 'installationId', 'numberOfPumps', 'operationalStatus',   'projectId','featureName'))

for field_map in list_of_fields_we_will_map:
    #Find the fields index by name. e.g 'TaxPin'
    field_to_map_index = fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex(field_map[0])  
    #Grab "A copy" of the current field map object for this particular field
    field_to_map = fieldmappings.getFieldMap(field_to_map_index)
    #Update its data source to add the input from the the append layer
    field_to_map.addInputField(append_layer, field_map[1])
    #We edited a copy, update our data grid object with it
    fieldmappings.replaceFieldMap(field_to_map_index, field_to_map)

#Create a list of append datasets and run the the tool
inData = [append_layer]
arcpy.Append_management(inData, target_layer, field_mappings=fieldmappings)

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
  File "d:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line 328, in getFieldMap
return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.GetFieldMap(*gp_fixargs(args)))
```

RuntimeError: FieldMappings: Error in getting field map from field mapping for GetFieldMap

**How do I field map my ssLateralLine feature to the WastewaterUtilitySegment features?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean the geometries aren't added with your first code. Add the `SHAPE@` token for [data access cursors](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) to your list of fields. It will insert your geometries.

```
outfcfield = ['SHAPE@', 'INSTALLDATE', 'FACILITYID', 'SIZE', 'InstallationID', 'DOWNELEV', 'UPELEV', 'SIZE', 'LIFECYCLE', 'MATERIAL', 'PROJECTID_ADD', 'SEGMENTTYPE']
infcfields = ['SHAPE@', 'equipDatePutInService', 'featureName', 'insideDiameter', 'installationId', 'invertElevationDownstream', 'invertElevationUom', 'nominalPipeSize', 'operationalStatus', 'pipeMaterial', 'projectId', 'wastewaterSegmentType']
```